# How to Process large JSON Data By MultiThreading in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to threading and Multithreading . I have a method which Fetches Ids as input in JSON format from DB as
{
"ID": ["1",
....,
.....
"30000"]}
Now these Ids are to be processed again via WebAPI POST call. The issue is,though the code is optimized, it is taking hours to process all data.
How can I process these Ids in batch or multi threading to make it faster?

Comment: Which part is taking the time, the webapi call? Are they singular calls? or are you sending the payload in one large chunk?

Comment: The best way is to check documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/using-threads-and-threading

Comment: The API Call is taking time, I am sending all the 30K ids all together to the API. @Michael Randall

Comment: Did you write the WebApi ? as that is *likely* the part that "may" benefit from parallel execution. Although you might be able to split the workloads up on the client side, and send concurrent requests

Comment: If you control the WebApi & have a function that takes in an ID and spits out the data that could be quite easy to parallelize.

Comment: What does the api do?

Comment: Perhaps the Parallel Class might help you in this [Parallel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netcore-3.1) this class will divide automatically to as many threads available to do the tasks as fast as possible

Comment: API is not under my control

Comment: As I understand you make the request to the API with 30k ids in one call is that correct? you don't do any processing yourself, the api does, and that takes time.

Comment: Not so fast. Before you start using multithreading, check what makes process to take long time. 1. If slowest is a computation which need to be executed, then - yes go for parallel approach to use multiple cores. 2. If slowest is an accessing of external resources (database, other web services or file system) - then using multiple threads would be wasting of that threads, because they will do nothing, but only waiting for the response from external resource. For external resources - use asynchronous approach (async - await) this will allow to wait for multiple requests simultaneously.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code and give some more details about the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of .NET have great libraries you can use that take care of the multi-threading for you.

Check out the Parallel For Each loop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netcore-3.1

You pass it a list and everything inside the loop is executed once for each item in the list and C# will do some of the iterations in parallel (multi-threaded). That means you could do your processing for more than one ID in parallel.

Whether or not it improves performance depends on the environment and work being done.